# list_route action does not show in Django REST framework docs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an action as shown below:

```
@list_route(url_path='posts/search')
    def search_posts(self, request):
        <some action>
```

Now, I am using DRF's [Built-in API documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/) to generate my API docs. But the above action does not show up. However, if I remove the `url_path` from `@list_route` then it shows up. Seems like the `url_path` has to match with the action name for the documentation generator to include it in the API docs. How can I fix this? I do not want to change the `url_path`.

Comment: It may be because you have a "/" in the url_path argument, have you tried changing url_path to "posts-search"?  It may be due to the fact that it uses the url_path to name the view router and "/" is not a valid character for the route name.

Comment: Yes that made it work!